# Why can I not view sites when I click on their links in google search?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

I'm having problems with google search link redirects.

For example, if I copy paste a link into my address bar, I'm fine. But if I were to click on that link in a google search, I get that the "connection was reset".

This has happened multiple times in Firefox and Chrome. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Sites like Google often behave differently when copying a link or when clicking it.

Like *copying* a link after searching for Super User, may simply give you http://superuser.com But when *clicking* it, Google will actually use JavaScript to send a HTTP POST to their server to count the fact that you clicked, and as a response they will then redirect you to the actual site. The URL being used is then something like:

> https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0C[...]AC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsuperuser.com%2F&ei=DI-d[...]g&usg=AF[...]bA&bvm=bv.8[...]WU

(I redacted the URL, so this will now give you a redirect warning you'd not get with a proper URL.)

This probably holds all kind of tracking info (and also the Google cookies are sent along with this POST), which might be blocked by a privacy-related plugin or virus scanner. So, disable those to find the cause.

(Also, Google keeps changing the way they show the search results. You might even get the long link when copying it. Not today, for me, on the English google.com.)